# Real-time notifications about link

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm looking for a way to get real-time notifications about a public link on Facebook being shared/liked/commented on. It is possible on Twitter via Twitter streaming API (filter.json?track=...). Does Facebook provide similar functionality? I know about the link_stats "table" in the FQL which can be easily queried but that would require polling and would not really be "real time".

Comment: Take a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/

Comment: Thanks, it looks like this API requires that the users have an app installed on their accounts. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. Real time updates are available only for User (and permissions), Page and Payments objects: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/

For reference, you can poll every X seconds to this url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.google.com
```

To get the the total "*shares*" (ie: likes+shared+occurrences_in_private_messages) of the url `http://www.google.com`

Comment: Thanks, but please read my question again. I know how to get aggregated data, FQL's link_stat table provides even more data. broken down into shares, comments and likes. What I'm trying to do is to get REAL TIME notifications about shares etc.

Comment: Ups, sorry! I've missed the no-polling part. Sadly there isn't a way, Real time updates are available only for User, Page, and Payments: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/